# How to center Ajax search bar on all screen sizes?

Tags: css, ajax, wordpress, center

My ajax search bar looks central on my mac screen, but on a phone screen, it is way off-center. 
Does anyone have a code that can 'float' it center on all screen sizes? 
The search bar in question is on www.rebelleforce.com
Thank you

I've tried various different CSS codes that I've found online in other forums - some centralize it on my mobile phone screen, but then I lose the central location on a computer screen.

Answer (score 0):

I see your code to centralize the search bar you use

```
div[id*='ajaxsearchlite'].wpdreams_asl_container {
width: 62%;
margin: 0px 250px 0px 250px;
}
```

try to change "margin" value to `margin:autio;`

Comment: sorry my mistake "margin:auto"

Answer (score 0):

paste this code into style.css file in your theme.

```
div[id*='ajaxsearchlite'].wpdreams_asl_container {
   width: 75% !important;
   margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

This code causes the search box to be centered on all screens.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your css:

```
#ajaxsearchlite2 {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and if still not working, use the important statement:

```
#ajaxsearchlite2 {
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```